# Packing grey scale images into a single color image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have 4 gray scale images that I need to pack into a single RGBA image. How can I do this in opencv? I know how to split an image in different channels, but I'm not sure about the other way around. I guess I could write easily a function from scratch. But maybe there's an opencv call for that.

Comment: `cv2.merge()` could help on this.

Comment: It's actually a duplicate. Shall I close the question?

Comment: @user8469759 Yeah, if it's a duplicate, then might as well get rid of it.